# Not able to connect MongoDB Atlas with Node.js trough Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to connect a Node.js application with MongoDB Atlas trough Mongoose and I'm getting the following error:

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the 
database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Users\marin\Downloads\Project part2\Project part2\docker_app\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:797:32)
    at C:\Users\marin\Downloads\Project part2\Project part2\docker_app\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:332:10
    at C:\Users\marin\Downloads\Project part2\Project part2\docker_app\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\marin\Downloads\Project part2\Project part2\docker_app\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\marin\Downloads\Project part2\Project part2\docker_app\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1153:10)     
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\marin\Downloads\Project part2\Project part2\docker_app\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:331:20)
    at connectDb (C:\Users\marin\Downloads\Project part2\Project part2\docker_app\src\connection.js:9:6)
    at Server.<anonymous> (C:\Users\marin\Downloads\Project part2\Project part2\docker_app\server.js:27:3)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:519:28) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'cluster0.huaic.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
  }
}
```

My code is:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const User = require("./User.model");

const connection = '"mongodb://cluster0.huaic.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase"';

const connectDb = () => {
  return mongoose
    .connect(connection)
    .then((res) => {
      return res;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
};

module.exports = connectDb;
```

I've allowed access from every IP on mongodb atlas and when I try to connect directly to atlas everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first, you have double quotes in the `connection` variable. Secondly: it seems to me that mongoUri should include the username and password in the query string, right?

Comment: You may also need to use a ["DNS Seed List"](https://docs.mongodb.com/upcoming/reference/connection-string/#std-label-connections-dns-seedlist) connection string (`mongodb+srv://`)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your connection string is like below. It should include your `username` and `password`:

```js
"mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.huaic.mongodb.net/yourdatabasename?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

Set up a user that has that `password` and that `username` by going to `Database Access` in your atlas account.